Lutris "i386 libGL.so.1 missing (needed by opengl)"
When starting Lutris this error is shown in the console. If i386 libGL.so.1 is needed or not a problem to install how to install it? Do I need to enable 32bit sources in sources.list? I already have libgl1 and libglu1-mesa-dev installed (on Debian 12).

You need to enable the i386 architecture:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update

Then you’ll be able to install the 32-bit libGL.so.1 library:
sudo apt install libgl1:i386


Is there any major downside to leaving that architecture enabled or should I better disable it after installing that package? After installing that package Lutris does not show this error anymore, I think Lutris should ask for this package to be installed then.

The only downside is that apt update takes slightly longer; you should leave the additional architecture enabled. I agree Lutris should be more explicit about this — it could at least mention how to address the warning in its README.Debian.
